# Testing mounted components with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router, enzyme

I'm migrating our application to `react-router@4.x`, and I'm having troubles with getting the tests that are using `enzyme`'s `mount` function.

Whenever I mount a component that has a `withRouter`-wrapped sub-component, I run into trouble.

Here's an example of a simplified situation of what I'm testing:

```
class SomePage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentWrappedInWithRouter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Component = (props) => (
  <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/new-route') }>
    Click to navigate
  </button>
);

const ComponentWrappedInWithRouter = withRouter(Component);
```

Now, I want to test that `SomePage` calls its prop `getData` after it's mounted. Stupid example, I know, but the structure should be sufficient.

Whenever I write a test that uses `enzyme`'s `mount`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
  at Route.computeMatch (node_modules/react-router/Route.js:68:22)
  at new Route (node_modules/react-router/Route.js:47:20)
```

Now, I think the reason this happens is because I try to call `withRouter` for a component that does not have `router` on the context - i.e. it has not been wrapped in `<BrowserRouter />` or one of its siblings.

This wasn't an issue with `react-router@3.x`, but since the current major was a full rewrite, I totally understand that these issues will arise.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy: wrap your component being tested in a `MemoryRouter` from `react-router-dom` and you're good to go.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md

Comment: The issue with that approach is that you no longer have access to the state of the component you're testing. So it kind of works - but not really. Also, it feels so wrong! ^^

Comment: Why is that? You can use `find` to dive into the component you mount since you're using `mount` and not `shallow`. I may be missing something of course, it's not clear what you mean with your original question :)

Comment: If I use `mount(...).find('SomePage').state()`, I get an error telling me that I can only access state of the root component - that is - the component that was mounted. And when wrapping things in `MemoryRouter`, that will be the root component. Tried to get into `SomePage` with both `dive` and `find` and trying to remount it - just couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? I've never had the need to peek into "state" in a component. Shouldn't you simply update state as necessary and verify the expected output? Your question was originally about solving the router issue but perhaps the real problem is something else.

Comment: Testing the state of a component might make sense in a ton of scenarios - but as you say, that's out of scope for this question.

Adding a `<MemoryRouter />` does work though - so I'll accept your answer for now :)

Comment: @CharlieBrown, I'm running into a similar issue of trying to access state on a component wrapped in `<MemoryRouter>`. I have a method who's only goal is to call `setState` to toggle a flag for whether or not a modal is open, so my assertions are checking to see if the flag has changed in state.


Is getting/setting component state a bad practice for testing? Enzyme has both getting/setting methods for state, so I always thought it was normal/okay.

Comment: Here are some examples from Enzyme on when [getting](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/state.html) and [setting](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setState.html) state may be desirable within a test